# Ignore characters in quotation marks inside a find and replace algorithm

Tags: python, syntax, lexical-analysis, transcoding

I have been wondering how I can make Python ignore characters inside double quotation marks (") in my find and replace function. My code is:

```
def findAndReplace(textToSearch, textToReplace,fileToSearch):
    oldFileName  = 'old-' + fileToSearch
    tempFileName = 'temp-' + fileToSearch
    tempFile = open( tempFileName, 'w' )
    for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
        tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
    tempFile.close()
    # Rename the original file by prefixing it with 'old-'
    os.rename( fileToSearch, oldFileName )
    # Rename the temporary file to what the original was named...
    os.rename( tempFileName, fileToSearch )
```

Suppose that our file (test.txt) has contents (THIS IS OUR ACTUAL TEXT):

*I like your code "I like your code"*

and I execute

```
findAndReplace('code','bucket',test.txt)
```

which will write the following to my file:

*I like your bucket "I like your bucket"*

However, I want it to skip the double-quoted part and get this as a result

*I like your bucket "I like your code"*

What should I add to my source code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can there be quotes inside quotes? In other words, does `I like your code "I like "your code""` actually have two quoted strings, `"I like "` and `""`, or one quoted string `"I like "your code""`?

Comment: These are the contents of the textfile, if I understand what you've just mentioned

Comment: I don't think you understand what I've just mentioned, because you didn't answer my question. But I'll assume that you'd want to treat the example the first way, not the second.

Comment: Yes there can be. The reason: The whole string is `'I like your code "I like your code"'` which is ONE string whereas two of its characters are double quotes

Comment: I think you're still not getting it, and I don't know how to explain it any better, but let me try one more time: That's one string with one quoted substring inside of it. `I like your code "I like your code" "I really like your code"` is, I assume, one string with _two_ quoted substrings inside of it. As long as the first example I gave it _also_ one string with two quoted substrings inside of it, everything is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
haystack = 'I like your code "I like your code"'
needle = "code"
replacement = "bucket"

parts = haystack.split('"')
for i in range(0,len(parts),2):
   parts[i] = parts[i].replace(needle,replacement)

print '"'.join(parts)
```

assuming you cannot have nested quotes ...

Comment: Basically the same as my answer, and you got there first… but I think it's simpler to use slicing and slice assignment to change the even bits, instead of mutating them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to handle quotes inside quotes, or anything like that, this is pretty easy. You could do it with regular expressions. But, since I'm guessing you don't know regexp (or you would have used it in the first place), let's do it with simple strings methods: `split` your string on quote characters, then `replace` only the even substrings, then `join` it back together:

```
for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    bits = line.split('"')
    bits[::2] = [bit.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace) for bit in bits[::2]]
    tempFile.write('"'.join(bits))
```